# Windows comments all my actions in headphones

Tags: windows-8

After accidentally pressing some kind of keyboard combination my Windows 8 started talking to me all actions I do on machine. How to disable this feature?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-xp/help/use-narrator - How to turn off voice narrator :)

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I turn off Narrator

You can turn off Narrator using  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Source [Turn on and use Narrator](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-xp/help/use-narrator)

---

#### How do I disable Narrator

To completely disable it see [How to Disable Windows 8 Narrator](http://www.mswinupdate.com/how-to-disable-windows-8-narrator/).